# Merge Items in List from different areas Python

Tags: python

This is driving me crazy. I have a script that pulls data from a csv. For each row it makes it a list. The reason is I want to merge two items based on a command line argument.

Here is my list as an example:

```
row = ['city', 'state', 'zip', 'zippostal', 'company']
```

Well I know if I do a join on row[0] and row[2] I will get

```
row = ['citystatezip', 'zippostal', 'company']
```

Well what if I wanted this....

```
row = ['companycityzip', 'state', 'zippostal']
```

How could I do this?

Edit:

Im sorry I didnt mean to be brief. What I have is a csv file with a bunch of data sometimes the city state and zip is in different fields but I need to merge them either by a , or - depends on what is needed. So what I did was make them into a list and based on command line arguements selecting what columns they are in I need them to merge so Ex.

column a   column b  column c  column d  ......
 city         state    zip        code

I need to merge column a into b by a ",". Well that works fine but sometimes column f will be the city and column a will be the state. So how to I merge them in a list and have both values end up in column a but still return the rest of the row minus the updated vaule.

Comment: What do you mean "a join on row[0] and row[2]"? And you have to be a lot more specific than "I wanted this": what do you mean about the selection by command line arguments? What code are you using so far?

Comment: i'm sure if you try to formulate your task without this obscure example, it would be 90% of solution.

Comment: Yes, please better describe the behavior you are looking for, preferably with a code example of what you have already tried.  What does the command line argument describe, and what is its format, at least in general?  What are the rules for transforming the list?

Comment: Not quite sure I understand the question could you give the reason you want to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this?:

```
>>> row = ['city', 'state', 'zip', 'zippostal', 'company']
>>> joins = [[4, 0, 2], [1], [3]]
>>> [''.join(row[i] for i in indices) for indices in joins]
['companycityzip', 'state', 'zippostal']
```

As a function:

```
def custom_join(row, *joins):
    return [''.join(row[i] for i in indices) for indices in joins]
```

Examples:

```
>>> row = ['city', 'state', 'zip', 'zippostal', 'company']
>>> custom_join(row, [0, 1, 2], [3], [4])
['citystatezip', 'zippostal', 'company']
>>> custom_join(row, [-1, 0, 2], [1], [-2])
['companycityzip', 'state', 'zippostal']
```

**Edit:** Here is a version that will return the remainder of the list after performing the joins:

```
def custom_join2(row, *joins):
    result = [''.join(row[i] for i in indices) for indices in joins]
    seen = set(i if i >= 0 else len(row)+i for indices in joins for i in indices)
    result.extend(v for i, v in enumerate(row) if i not in seen)
    return result

>>> custom_join2(row, [-1, 0, 2])
['companycityzip', 'state', 'zippostal']
```

Comment: That is exactly what I needed. Thank you very much. I do have one other question. Is there way to have it do that no matter how much is in the row. Because the row may have 4 items in it sometimes 200. But based on the arguments given it will just do those.

Comment: @thedemon Edited my answer with an alternate version that I think should do what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This is my best guess for what your asking:

```
row = ['city', 'state', 'zip', 'zippostal', 'company']
temp_list = []
temp_str = row[4]+row[0]+row[2]
temp_list.append(temp_str)
temp_list.append(row[1])
temp_list.append(row[3])
row = temp_list  # ['companycityzip', 'state', 'zippostal']
```

though I feel you want something dynamic which this is not